# Concurrent users for an 802.11ac AP

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

In theoretical and practical, how many concurrent users (4 Mbps each) should have associated to an AP which can deliver 802.11ac, 1.3Gbps of bitrate?

Comment: When I tested again the AP in a indoor environment.. it can associate up to 25 clients.. the AP ping 30000 to each client.. so far didnt see any low txccq issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Cisco, it could exceed 100 clients simultaneously.

[Cisco APs](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/wireless/buyers-guide.html#~indoorac-wave1)

But from my point of view, 30 - 40 clients per AP might be fine. The more clients, the lower performance. Besides, because the 802.11ac uses the 5 GHz channels, the coverage area will be smaller than the device using 802.11n.

Wireless performance can be affected by too many factors. Also, if some devices are too far from the AP, it will lower the performance of the AP significant. A healthy wireless network doesn't relies on the performance of a single AP. A good design and suitable roaming configuration will be a big plus.

Comment: Thanks Steven. Cisco AP can support 100 clients streaming video of 4Mbps simultaneously Would the performance be much different between indoor environment and outdoor environment.

Comment: There are dedicated model for outdoor scenario. The most difference between the indoor model and outdoor model are the endurance. The temperature range of the outdoor model could be -40 to 65.

Comment: I have tested in outdoor environment (distance around 20-30m between AP and Station), my AP is always can associate to 15 clients only. Each of the clients transmitting 4Mbps of video.. 15x4Mbps = 60Mbps. The AP I test running 11ac protocol which can deliver 1.3Gbps of bitrate, it should have associate to more that 15 clients.

Comment: @Jess The 1.3Gbps is the theoretical rate. As I have mentioned above, please do not leave the client being far away with your AP. If you move the client to 5m away from the AP, are you able to connect more clients?

Comment: I understood the real environment results does vary with theoretical. 20-30m distance is the environment of my setup application. I'm still figuring out how to let more clients able connect to it. I feel that 15 clients are just not good enough for a 11ac AP.

Comment: @Jess "20-30m distance is the environment of my setup application." You may need some tools to detect the signal strength. "I feel that 15 clients are just not good enough for a 11ac AP" Yeah, normally, an enterprise CA should be able to serve 30 - 40 clients stably.

Comment: I can check the RSSI in the AP webUI.. all 15 clients are averagely showing good tx-ccq.

Comment: @Jess What errors did you encounter when you tried to connect the 16th device? The AP side log might be more helpful

Comment: It did not have errors show.. the 16th device just never get linked up with the AP =(

Comment: @Jess Weird. Did you consult with the support of the AP about this issue or limitation?

Comment: yup I did. Then I tested again the AP in a indoor environment.. it can associate up to 25 clients.. without transmitting video, do ping as normal only.

Comment: @Jess Is there any possibility that other wireless signal may jam your AP outdoor? Some wireless network will not broadcast their SSID.

Comment: This is unlikely.